# How to set local variable memberExpression value

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I want to get parameter original name and update its value. How can I do this?

```
public void SetMember<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
    var name = body.Member.Name; //text

    //can I set variable value here 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text="test";
    SetMember(() => text);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, the local variable is captured in an object which will be stored as a constant in the expression tree.

You can either compile a new method that sets the value of the captured field:

```
public static void SetMember<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression, T newVlaue)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
    var name = body.Member.Name; //text
    var newValueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var newBody = Expression.Assign(body, newValueParam);

    var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(newBody, newValueParam).Compile();
    setter(newVlaue); // Set with the new value 
}
```

Or you can use reflection of the constant value

```
public static void SetMember<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression, T newVlaue)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
    var name = body.Member.Name; //text
    var constant = body.Expression as ConstantExpression;

    (body.Member as FieldInfo).SetValue(constant.Value, newVlaue);
}
```

**NOTE** Just because you can do this does not mean you should. This depends on the internals of variable capture and could change with a new implementation of the compiler. And don't think it will not happen, when the C# compiler switched to Roslyn there was a change in whether some anonymous function were turned into static or instance methods which broke some 'clever code' I wrote, so use at your own peril.

A cleaner approach would be to use `out` / `ref` parameters if you just want to set a local variable, and `nameof` if you need the name of the variable for some reason, this will be faster cleaner and more reliable, but does require you to use the local variable in two places.

```
public static void SetMember<T>(ref T local, T newValue, string nameOfLocal)
{
    local = newValue;
    // nameofLocal can be used ..
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = "test";
    SetMember(ref text, "new value", nameof(text));
    Console.Write(text);
}
```

Comment: @LEI don't forget to mark as answered if it was the answer to your question :)